# Periodic binary sequence: Generation of unique periodic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, periodic-functions

My question is a follow up on 
[Binary sequence count of unique patterns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839310/binary-sequence-count-of-unique-patterns)

I understand how to count the number of periodic sequences that can be generated using a specific number of bits (as solved in the link above).

However, I would like to know if there exist some way to generate all the possible unique periodic sequences (without solving for all possible permutations). For example:

given 3 digits, the unique periodic sequences will be:

000

100 (equivalent to: 010,001)

110 (equivalent to: 011,101)

111

Thus, there are four unique periodic sequences that are possible.
**I** have generated those using all possible permutations and reducing them to "canonical" forms. However, given 12 digits, this becomes a heavy task.

Thus, I would like to know if there exist some general representation of all possible unique periodic sequences for a given number of bits (or for a given period) such that by a change of parameter I can get them all.

So far, I have found the following result:

The defining function of periodic sequence of N bits is defined as:

$ f(k) = \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j(e^{\frac{2\pi}{N}i})^{jk} $

where $i = \sqrt{-1}$ and $k \in [1,2,3,4,...]$.

In order to find the appropriate $a_j$ one may solve the following:

$ \mathbf{E} \mathbf{a} = \text{any combination of 1 and 0 in vector form}$

Here:

$ E_{jk} = (e^{\frac{2\pi}{N}i})^{jk}$ ($j$ and $k$ are integers in $[1,N]$) and $\mathbf{a}$ gathers $a_j$ into vector form.

The interesting thing is that: for any unique periodic binary sequence there will be a distnct $|\mathbf{a}|$ (i.e a vector with absolute values of the components of $\mathbf{a}$ and not its norm) relating to it.

It can be used on permutations but I cannot go on and define a single parameter or equation such that it will result in unique periodic sequences. (and I believe such one exists)

Comment: Are you allowing all permutations or just cycles?  It doesn't make a difference for $n = 3$ but will matter for larger $n$.

Comment: I am allowing just cycles. so for n = 5 for example I have: 10000 which is the unique form equivalent to 01000,00100,00010,00001. (which I do not care for and in fact want to eliminate as options)

Comment: What is $0011$ equivalent to?

Comment: This: 1001,1100,0110

Answer (score 1):

The following provides the periodic sequences with 12 bits in 0.2 seconds (and could be much improved, using C or compiled functions). The idea is to define a canonical form by considering, among all cycles, the one corresponding to the maximal value. In the following *Mathematica* code, this is done by converting the bits to the decimal base (`FromDigits`).

```
can[l_] := Block[{list},  lists = NestList[RotateLeft, l, Length[l] - 1];
              Flatten@MaximalBy[lists, FromDigits[#, 2] &, 1]]
```

For example `can[{1,0,1}]` and `can[{0,1,1}]` both returns `{1,1,0}`.

Then it suffices to convert all binary numbers from $0$ to $2^{12}$ and remove the duplicates:

```
PadLeft[#, 12] & /@ Table[can[IntegerDigits[i, 2]], {i, 1, 2^12}] 
   // DeleteDuplicates // AbsoluteTiming

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0} 
    ...
*)
```

It takes 5 seconds for 16 digits (again, it can be significantly reduced).